# Select rows where one column is within a day of another column

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables from a site similar to SO: one with posts, and one with up/down votes for each post. I would like to select all votes cast on the day that a post was modified.

**My tables layout is as seen below:**

Posts:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| post_id | post_author | modification_date   |
-----------------------------------------------
| 0       | David       | 2012-02-25 05:37:34 |
| 1       | David       | 2012-02-20 10:13:24 |
| 2       | Matt        | 2012-03-27 09:34:33 |
| 3       | Peter       | 2012-04-11 19:56:17 |
| ...     | ...         | ...                 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Votes (each vote is only counted at the end of the day for anonymity):

```
-------------------------------------------
| vote_id | post_id | vote_date           |
-------------------------------------------
| 0       | 0       | 2012-01-13 00:00:00 |
| 1       | 0       | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
| 2       | 0       | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
| 3       | 0       | 2012-04-12 00:00:00 |
| 4       | 1       | 2012-02-21 00:00:00 |
| ...     | ...     | ...                 |
-------------------------------------------
```

**What I want to achieve**:

```
-----------------------------------
| post_id | post_author | vote_id |
-----------------------------------
| 0       | David       | 1       |
| 0       | David       | 2       |
| 1       | David       | 4       |
| ...     | ...         | ...     |
-----------------------------------
```

I have been able to write the following, but it selects all votes on the day **before** the post modification, not on the same day (so, in this example, an empty table):

```
SELECT Posts.post_id, Posts.post_author, Votes.vote_id
FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Votes ON Posts.post_id = Votes.post_id
WHERE CAST(Posts.modification_date AS DATE) = Votes.vote_date;
```

How can I fix it so the `WHERE` clause takes the day before `Votes.vote_date`? Or, if not possible, is there another way?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which type of database you are using (SQL, Oracle ect..);To take the Previous days votes you can usually just subtract 1 from the date and it will subtract exactly 1 day:

```
Where Cast(Posts.modification_date - 1 as Date) = Votes.vote_date
```

or if modification_date is already in date format just:

```
Where Posts.modification_date - 1 = Votes.vote_date
```

Comment: Note that SQL Server does not, in general, allow you to subtract one day from a `date` data type using `-`, although it does allow you to subtract a day from `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a site similar to Stack Overflow, then perhaps you also use SQL Server:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_author, v.vote_id
FROM Posts p LEFT JOIN
     Votes v
     ON p.post_id = v.post_id
WHERE CAST(DATEDIFF(day, -1, p.modification_date) AS DATE) = v.vote_date;
```

Different databases have different ways of subtracting one day.  If this doesn't work, then your database has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution, which is to add a day to `Posts.modification_date`:

```
...
WHERE CAST(CEILING(CAST(p.modification_date AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) = v.vote_date
```